# why action in <h:commandLink> doesn't work inside a composite component

Tags: jsf-2, composite-component

I have a very simple JSF 2/Facelets page that looks like this:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{myBean.names}" var="_name">
  <h:commandLink value="#{_name}" action="#{myBean.sayHello(_name)}">
    <f:ajax execute="@this"/>
  </h:commandLink>
  <br/>
</ui:repeat>
```

The backing bean provides a `java.util.List<String>` with names and the action-method just prints a `"hello <name>"` message to standard output.

This works fine. I get a list of names in the browser and a click fires the action-method that says hello to the specified name.

The Problem arises, when I want to put this code in a composite component that does the iteration and renders the actual link via a facet:

```
<ui:component xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
              xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
              xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
              xmlns:cc="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/composite">
  <cc:interface>
    <cc:attribute name="value" type="java.util.List" required="true" />
    <cc:facet name="content" />
  </cc:interface>
  <cc:implementation>
   <ui:repeat value="#{cc.attrs.value}" var="_name">
     <cc:renderFacet name="content"/>
   </ui:repeat>
  </cc:implementation>
</ui:component>
```

I use the composite component like this:

```
<my:myComp value="#{bean.names}">
  <f:facet name="content">
    <h:commandLink value="#{_name}" action="#{bean.sayHello(_name)}">
      <f:ajax execute="@this"/>
    </h:commandLink>
    <br/>
  </f:facet>
</my:myComp>
```

In the browser I get a list of names that looks exactly like before. But clicking a link now renders a `"hello null"` message. So `_name` is resolved correctly in the `value` attribute of `<h:commandLink>` but not in the `action` attribute.

I also tried using `actionListener` instead of `action` or the `listener` attribute from the `<f:ajax>` tag with no difference.

Could anybody shade some light on this issue?

My environment:

- WildFly 8.1 with
- JSF 2.2.6 (Mojarra)

Answer (score 1):

The issue has to do with the scope of the variable in this case `_name` which is evaluated once when the `<ui:repeat/>` is being processed. In my case, I ran your code and it produced `Hello John` even though their were other names in my list. To get around this, I introduced a `<f:param/>` that would contain the value of the `_name`, and modified your code as follows:

```
    <h:form>
        <my:myComp value="#{bean.names}">
            <f:facet name="content">
                <h:commandLink value="#{_name}" action="#{bean.sayHello()}">
                    <f:param name="name_" value="#{_name}"/>
                    <f:ajax execute="@this"/>
                </h:commandLink>
                <br/>
            </f:facet>
        </my:myComp>
    </h:form>
```

I also modified the `sayHello()` method as follows for a `@RequestScoped` bean:

```
@ManagedProperty(value = "#{facesContext}")
private FacesContext facesContext;

public void setFacesContext(FacesContext facesContext) {
    this.facesContext = facesContext;
}

public void sayHello() {
    Map<String, String> params = facesContext.getExternalContext()
                .getRequestParameterMap();
    String name = params.get("name_");
    System.out.println("Hello " + name);
}
```

You could change this to something shorter in a `@ViewScoped` bean to:

```
 public void sayHello() {
    Map<String, String> params = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance()
            .getExternalContext().getRequestParameterMap();
    String name = params.get("name_");
    System.out.println("Hello " + name);
}
```

The final result is that it prints out the names correctly.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Your workaround is valid and that's actually how I have it already (wanted to post this later). Unfortunately you don't explain the details, why the variable gets resolved one time (for value) but not another time (for action). And that's what I'm actually interested in. Could you also provide this information, please?

Comment: There is a very good explanation with examples here: [Values of h:inputText inside ui:repeat are not processed](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16550781/160361)

Comment: I'm quite sure, that's something different. My code works outside a composite component and doesn't call any setter. And the variable seems to be set as I can output it's value. Beside this, I tried using a wrapper like in your posted link with no difference in behavior.

Comment: @JohnYearly, I gave you an upvote for the workaround. Still the actual question is not answered, yet.