# How can I pass the value of a range variable, as a parameter to a java method, which is passed as value, for an attribute of a primefaces element?

Tags: java, html, primefaces, spring-webflow

in order to get a better understanding of the question, I suggest you to take a look at the following code:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{Reports}" var="r">
   <div>
      <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{myService.ConvertIdToTrueOrFalse(r.Id)}"/>
   </div>
</ui:repeat>
```

In this piece of code I have a collection with the name `Reports` and I am using `r` as my range variable, in order to iterate through my collection.

I have also a service called `myService`.

I use `<p:selectBooleanCheckbox/>` from primefaces.

What I am trying to do, is to call in each iteration the `ConvertIdToTrueOrFalse` method from `myService` and pass the `Id` as input parameter.

Unfortunately, for some reason `r.Id` is not recognized and it takes somehow 0 value.

How can I make the code recognize that `r.Id` is coming from the `Reports` collection?

Is there a special character that I have to use in order to signalize that `r.Id` comes from `Reports` collection?

The funny part is that the following code returns me the Ids from the collection as expected:

```
<ui:repeat value="#{Reports}" var="r">
   <div>#{r.Id}</div>
</ui:repeat>
```

If you have any ideas or suggestions, please let me know.

Comment: Have you tried <p:selectBooleanCheckbox value="#{myService.ConvertIdToTrueOrFalse(" + #{r.Id} + ")}"/> ? Since this might be a problem with r.Id being interpeted as a String in the html, and in the Java code it thinks r is an Object that it can't find while really the Java code should get a value.

Comment: Is the answer in here (using varStatus)? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16545731/values-of-hinputtext-inside-uirepeat-are-not-processed

Comment: @OrvilNordström: I tried this out but unfortunately it does not work

Comment: @Kukeltje: I do not know what varStatus is

Comment: sorry to be so blunt, but there are these things called 'search engine'. Several exist... and there is an example in the link I used (did you read it?)